# How to Change the Format of current Date when storing it in mongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In the schema of mongoDB, I am trying to store current date using date.now(), but it is storing date in UTC format. How can I change the date format in local date?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores dates in [BSON Date type](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/bson-data-types-date/#:%7E:text=The%20recommended%20way%20to%20store,UTC%20on%201%20January%201970.), UTC timestamp with 64-bit integer internally. What you want is store dates as local date formatting, just store them already formatted `String`, not `Date`. What you want is to see date values as local time, consider using [`$dateToString`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) aggregation expression.

For example:

```js
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      createdAt: { $dateToString: { date: '$createdAt', timezone: 'Asia/Seoul' } }
    }
  }
])

//    { "_id": ..., "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-02T04:52:02.237Z") }
// -> { "_id": ..., "createdAt": "2020-12-02T13:52:02.237Z" }
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, it should be noted that you should **always** store `Date` objects (time in UTC). Use `$dateToString` only for **displaying** of the data!

Comment: As @Wernfried said, storing dates in other type is rare and makes manipulating data hard - MongoDB's [Date expression operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators) only work with `Date` objects.